# How to fit a curve to data with sd in R?

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I'm completely new to R, so apologies for asking something I'm sure must be basic. I just wonder if I can use the nls() command in R to fit a non-linear curve to a data structure where I have means and sd's, but not the actual replicates. I understand how to fit a curve to single data points or to replicates, but I can't see how to proceed when I have a mean+sd for each data point and I want R to consider variation in my data when fitting.

Comment: take a look at `nlme::gnls` and the `weights` argument

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to go would be to simulate data using your means and standard deviations and do the regression with the simulated data. Doing this a number of times could give you a good impression on the margin of plausible values for your regression coefficients.